# To "FORK" or to "SPAWN" - this is the question

Tags: c, linux, server, fork, spawn

I have a server (TCP), implemented in "C", running on modern Linux servers.

Server handle large number (>50 req/second). The server is single threaded - it integrate 3rd party code that is NOT thread-safe (can not be modified). Some requests are "fast" (milliseconds), and some requests are "slow" (require lot of processing).

Overtime, the size of the heap for the "main" server becomes significant (> 8GB).

Current logic is to conditionally **FORK** the "slow" requests, and perform the "fast" requests in the main threads.

I'm trying to optimize the performance of the "slow" requests, as I found that forking become expensive, when the "main" server heap size is significant. I'm trying use the **SPAWN** calls (running modern Linux), to create a fresh instance of the server, passing minimal information to it via command line, and letting it read the payload from a file descriptor. Basically:

```
Read request header (short - about 50 bytes)
if slow-request then
    if "big-heap"
        spawn new instant of the server, pass header as command line parameters
        read request data via passed fd (stdin ?)
    else
        read request data (in forked process)
    process requests - parallel to main thread
    exit
else
    run in main thread
```

My Question:

1. Does anyone has experience with this approach ? Specifically, what is a good rule to execute new instances of the process, instead of "fork".
2. Any pitfalls to be aware of ?
3. Any existing benchmarking for defining the "big-heap" test ?

I did not dig too much into how "spawn" is working on Linux, but I believe it is smarter/more efficient than plain "fork/exec".

Comment: *"Overtime, the size of the heap for the "main" server becomes significant"*  Is this because of the slow requests, or the consequence of a **memory leak?**

Comment: On a "modern Linux server", fork/exec will probably be faster than spawn, since it is just creating a new process and copy-on-write of the existing address space. A better architecture might be to run as many processes as you have cores and use a front end process to do load balancing of requests in shared memory.

Comment: @mmixLinus process grows because of internal working (not a leak). It's acting as in memory cache.

Comment: @stark I do not control the underlining code/logic (otherwise, I would have tried to make it MT safe). Can not switch architecture for same reason. The cost of the COW becomes significant. I've notice fork cost going up significantly for large processes.